# If a function $f(x,y,z) = F(r)$ depends on distance from the origin, $r = \|\vec{r}\| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$, then $\nabla f = F'(r)e_{\vec{r}}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

How do I prove the above? I've tried this:

Given $\vec{r} = \langle x, y, z \rangle \quad e_{\vec{r}} = \frac{\vec{r}}{\|\vec{r}\|}\quad r = \|r\| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$

Since $F(r) = f(x,y,z)$, then

$$F'(r)e_{\vec{r}} = \frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial r}e_{\vec{r}} =  \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}  \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial r} \right)
\frac{\vec{r}}{\|\vec{r}\|}
=\nabla f \cdot \langle \frac{\partial x}{\partial r},\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial z}{\partial r} \rangle \frac{\vec{r}}{\|\vec{r}\|} = \nabla f$$

This is not exactly correct because I don't know how $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{x}{r}$ reduces to 1 or if it does.

Comment: I'd recommend starting from the other "direction". I.e. calculate $\nabla f$. Note that, for example, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} $... See Chilango's post below (which was typed as I typed this comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the definition and then use the chain rule on each term:

$$\nabla f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec i+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vec j+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\vec k=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\vec i+\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\vec j+\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial z}\vec k=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\left ( \frac{x}{r}\vec i+\frac{y}{r}\vec j+\frac{z}{r}\vec k \right )=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\vec e_r$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\nabla F
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
By the chain rule, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=F'(r)\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=F'(r)\cdot \frac{x}{r}$. Therefore,
$$
\nabla F
=
\frac{F'(r)}{r}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}=\frac{F'(r)}{r}\mathbf{r}=F'(r)\mathbf{e}_r
$$